# Not able to find which Products are associated with opportunity in Exported data

Tags: opportunity, data-export

I just exported Opportunity Object records using APEXDataLoader.
Exported data have few opportunity records to which few products are associated.

But in exported data I'm not able to find which products are associated with opportunity.

Opportunity are associated with Pricebooks.
Then I exported Pricebook object in which i find what products are present in that Pricebook.

But I'm not able to find direct connection between Opportunity and there associated products.

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Opportunity Product is the sObject that stores information about which Products are associated with which Opportunity. The API name is `OpportunityLineItem`. Here is the documentation: https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm

If you export this object and compare to your Opportunity export, there will be multiple Opportunity Product rows for each Opportunity, related by `OpportunityId`. Each Opportunity Product row will also have a `Product2Id` and `PriceBookEntryId`, either of which can be used to look up which Product it is for.